# Holder's inequality and Minkowski's inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Can somebody explain me how to use Holder's inequality and Minkowski's inequality. Can these inequalities be used to solve the problem that if $x, y, k$ are non negative  reals then prove that 
$$\left(1+\frac{x}{y}\right)^k +\left(1+ \frac{y}{x}\right)^k \ge 2^{k+1}$$
Edit 1- My main question is about what Holder's inequality and minkowski's inequality are and how do we use them

Comment: This inequality is solved here by AM-GM: [Prove the inequality $({1+\frac{a}b})^n$ + $(1+\frac{b}a)^n$ $\geq$ $2^{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753593/prove-the-inequality-1-fracabn-1-fracban-geq-2n1)

Comment: My main question is about what Holder's inequality and minkowski's inequality are and how do we use them

Comment: If that is the case, why would you accept rather quickly answer that does  not address the Holder/Minkowski either? Anyway it is better to ask just one specific question, otherwise it confuse people (I haven't marked it as a duplicate though). Also questions of type "How to use Holder inequality" are quite generic, this site contains many Holder/Minkowski inequalities examples, you can just look at them.

Comment: I asked the question so as it could be solved by Holder's inequality but the easy application of AM GM inequality itself provided the answer. So I felt there was no need to use Holder's inequality when the question can be solved so easily and accepted the answer. And sorry for any inconvenience hence caused.And thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is not true if you allow $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $x = 1, y = -1$:

$$\left(1 + \frac{x}y\right)^k + \left(1 + \frac{y}x\right)^k = 0^k + 0^k = 0 < 2^{k+1}$$

However, it can be proved with AM-GM inequality if you assume $x,y > 0$:

\begin{align}\left(1 + \frac{x}y\right)^k + \left(1 + \frac{y}x\right)^k &= \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\frac{x^k}{y^k} + \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\frac{y^k}{x^k} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\left(\frac{x^k}{y^k} + \frac{y^k}{x^k}\right) \\
&\ge \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\cdot 2\sqrt{\frac{x^k}{y^k} \cdot \frac{y^k}{x^k}}\\
&= 2 \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}\\
&= 2\cdot 2^k\\
&= 2^{k+1}
\end{align}